# Problem with uiimageView animation: animation stops

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, timer, uiimageview

Here is my code:

```
-(void) createNewBall {

  UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bulle_03.png"];
  bulleBouge = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

  [bulleBouge setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];
  [[self view] addSubview:bulleBouge];

}

-(void)moveTheBall{

  bulleBouge.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);

}
```

`createNewBall` is called every two seconds. My problem is that every `bulleBouge` that is created stops moving after two seconds. I don't know why.

How can I solve this please?

Answer (score 3):

It stops moving b/c u are initializing new bulleBouge every two seconds. You are also leakin memory since you never releasy it before assigning new value to it.  so what happens is that after u create the imageView you only keep the reference to the lasts instance, hence only the last one is changing position. To fix this store all your new uiImageViews in an array and move them randomly after two seconds.

```
-(void) createNewBall {

  UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bulle_03.png"];
  UIImageView *bulleBouge = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
  [bulleBouge setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];

  [bulleBougeArray addObject:bulleBouge];

  [[self view] addSubview:bulleBouge];

  [bulleBouge release];

}

-(void)moveTheBall{

  for(int i=0; i< [bulleBougeArray count];i++){
    UIImageView *bulleBouge = [bulleBougeArray objectAtIndex:i];
    bulleBouge.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
   }

}
```

Comment: but if I want an infinite number of uiimageViews i won't be able to store them in an array.

Comment: Check my edit for the code. As for infinite, there is no such thing, you will not be able to store infinite stuff anywhere, but you can handle the overload by removing object that are already out of the view scope.

Comment: so in .h I declare "NSArray*imageViewArray;" then with your code I have two warnings, first NSArray may not respond to addObject and the second "local declaration of bulleBouge hides instance variable" for the line  UIImageView *bulleBouge = [bulleBougeArray objectAtIndex:i];. this code not seems to work, I try it and it doesn't work

Comment: If you look up the docs, you'll see that [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) is actually an immutable array (i.e. it can not be modified). That's why the -addObject: message is not implemented. Instead, you will need to use [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/).

Comment: AND about "local declaration of bulleBouge hides instance variable" warning you must have declared the imageview globally, with above code you don't need to have a global iVar for imageview (i.e UIImageView *bulleBouge)

Comment: yes but if I don't have a global iVar I can't use it in "createNewBall" method, it will be declared only in moveTheBall

Answer (score 0):

Cyprian is correct. In a simpler form, you're creating a new bulleBouge every two seconds, under the same variable. The program already has one, but since you told it to make a new one under the same ivar it forgets the old one, and thus doesn't move it. You need an array so that each ball can be remembered separately, and thus moved separately as seen in the example code that he posted.

Comment: I use his code but it doesn't work, I don't know why? I have never used array, but I think that something is missing in his code ?

Comment: You won't be able to copy his code exactly, as people will make frowny faces at you and he hasn't allocated the array in that snippet of code. See here for a tutorial on adding and animating multiple things. http://maniacdev.com/2010/08/beginners-iphone-action-game-tutorial/3/

Comment: yes but if I want to have 100 balls, I won't put them all in an array. Indeed what I want is to have 100 balls, and all the same

Comment: An array is how you would handle a hundred balls anyway. The only problem I see there is whether or not the iphone has enough processing power to handle animating 100 different balls all at once.

Comment: no not all at once look at this video it is exactly what I wanna do http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rD3MTTPaK98

Comment: The app in the video is doing one of two things. Creating the balls and adding a complete animation (giving the balls the finish location and attaching the animation), or using an array. An array is best way to go since you can access the balls at a later time. What you misunderstand is that the array will never actually contain an infinite number of balls; even if the balls were 1 px wide the screen can't contain that many.